# Length of segment

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

The two circles in the diagram are incircles of $\triangle{ADB}$ and $\triangle{ADC}$.
These incircles are tangent to $AD$ and each other at $G$.

i) If $AB=c$,$AC=b$ and $BC=a$, find the length of $BD$ in terms of $a,b$ and $c$.

ii) Let the radii of the two circles in the diagram be $r$ and $s$.Show that the length of $DE$ is $\sqrt{rs}$.

**Efforts made:** Working on the first part of the problem  i tried to relate the tangents of the incircles to the legs of  triangle $\triangle{ABC}$ in order to get an expression for $BD$ but as far as i try i always get something like $BD=2a + 2b -c +x$ where $x$ is some tangent to one of the two incircles.
[image]

**Note:** If you can give me only hints,it would be best.thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O_1,O_2$ be the incircle of $\triangle{ADB},\triangle{ADC}$ respectively. Also, let $H$ be the point on $O_1$ tangent to $AB$, and let $I$ be the point on $O_2$ tangent to $AC$.

> If you can give me only hints,it would be best.

For i) Let $AH=x,BH=y,CI=z,DE=w$. Then, since $AG=AI=x,BE=y,CF=z,DG=DF=w$, we have
$$a=y+2w+z,\quad b=x+z,\quad c=x+y.$$

So, $BD=y+w=\cdots$

For ii) Each of $\angle{O_1GD},\angle{O_2GD},\angle{O_1ED},\angle{O_2FD}$ is equal to $90^\circ$. So, $O_1E$ is parallel to $O_2F$. And $O_1+O_2=r+s,EF=2w$. Consider the quadrilateral $O_1O_2FE$.

Comment: thanks for the hints .i solved the problem...sometimes it's really frustrating to    see that you had the right approach but you didn't manage to solve the problem .However answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Complete solution for the sake of reference:
Let $O_1$ and $O_2$ be the incircles of $\triangle{ADB}$ and $\triangle{ADC}$ respectively. Also, let $H$ be the point on $O_1$ tangent to $AB$, and let $I$ be the point on $O_2$ tangent to $AC$.

Let $AH=x,BH=y,CI=z,$ and $DE=w$. Then $$\begin{cases}AB=x+y\\ BC=y+2w+z \\ AC=x+z\end{cases}$$
From here you can verify that $BD=y+w=\frac{AB+BC-AC}{2}$.

Since $\angle FEO_1=EFO_2=90^\circ$, $O_1O_2FE$ is a trapezoid. 
Assuming that $r>s$, let $X$ be a point on $O_1E$ such that $XEFO_2$ is a rectangle. Since $O_1O_2=r+s$, we have that $XO_2=\sqrt{(r+s)^2-(r-s)^2}=2\sqrt{rs}$. So $ED=
​\frac{1}{2}EF=\frac{1}{2}XO_2=\sqrt{rs}$ as desired.